# Пара координат вывод

Tags: java

Как создать n пар координат (x,y),как реализовать через цикл или по другому?

Comment: Не понятно, а какие проблемы имеют место быть?

Comment: не могу сделать так,чтобы создавались переменные в количестве n пар,в которых имеются по 2 координаты,не знаю как это записать,недавно только начал изучать язык

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class Test {

    class Pair {
        int x;
        int y:

        public Pair(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
    }

    public static void Main(String[] args) {
        List<Pair> coords = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            coords.add(new Pair(i, i));
        }
    }
}
```